# Comparing two table schemas and generate the Alter table query for SQL databases

Tags: java, schema, liquibase, flyway, sqldatasource

I have a requirement where I have two tables in two different databases, where one is source and other is destination. I have to pull the table schema between source table and destination table and see if it is backward compatible. Suppose user added a new column or an existing data type is changed for a column in the source I should be able to generate a DDL alter table query to make the changes in the destination table and should work for any SQL database.

I have looked into tools like flyway and liquibase to see if it can do the required changes, but It doesn't fit the requirement. Is there anyway to meet such requirement with any existing tools like liquibase or flyway? Iam writing the code in Java.

If anyone had similar situation before please throw some light into this.

Comment: Which specific database are you using?

Comment: @DavidAtkinson Iam not trying to do this for a specific database but for almost all the SQLdatabases and try to generalize it.

Comment: It would help to know which one you have tried this with, as this may be relevant to where you've hit limitations in the tools that you've tried.

Comment: Currently I have only tested with Mysql.

Comment: Flyway Enterprise edition (not the Community edition) can version MySQL database schema changes and auto-generate migration scripts from these changes.

Comment: Is there any opensource tools you are aware of.

Comment: If you do a web search for "MySQL Comparison tools" you should get a bunch of different options. I'm not sure if there any robust OSS options.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAtkinson But I was really looking for generalized approach to solve this.